# Does PL/SQL have the equivalent of array params in C#?

Tags: c#, plsql, parameters

In C#, if you set up a method parameter using the `params` keyword, that parameter will take in an indefinite number of arguments. When calling the method, you can then send a comma-separated list of arguments for that parameter.

Does PL/SQL have an equivalent feature for method parameters?

Thanks!

Andrew L

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The `params` keyword is syntactic sugar that is converted to an array by the compiler. Oracle apparently is less 'sweet'. The closest you can get is create a procedure that accepts a variable-size array (`Varray`).

Comment: You can use one of three collection types in PL/SQL: associative tables (hash like), nested tables (set like) and varray (C-array like). Check the [documentation on collection](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/composites.htm#CIHIEBJC) for details.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a temporary table, I suppose this is the most common option because it probably works in most RDBMS.

In SQL Server 2008 though, you can even pass a table parameter, like:

```
CREATE TYPE my_table_type AS TABLE(a int NOT NULL,
                                   b int NOT NULL)

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[test]
(
    @model my_table_type readonly
)
AS
BEGIN
END
```